# Magento Ce 1.9.0.1 :Getting Problem in Most Viewed Products

Tags: magento-1.9, products

I am trying to get most viewed products in magento ce 1.9.0.1 by getting help from an [article](http://blog.magikcommerce.com/how-to-show-most-viewed-best-selling-products-in-magento-store) :

Create a file `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Mostviewed.php` and add the following lines of code in it

```
<?php class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}?>
```

Create a file `app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml` and add the following code in it

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class=" most_viewed">
<div class="mv_title"><?php echo $this->__('These Products Are Popular Right Now!') ?></div>
<?php $_collectionSize = 5;//count($_products->getItems()); echo $_collectionSize; ?>
<ul class="products-grid" id="products-grid-table">
<?php $i=1; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
    <li id="td_<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i%5==0 or $i==$_collectionSize){echo 'class="last"';} ?> >
        <div id="cont_<?php echo $i;?>">        
            <a class="product-image" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
            </a>
            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h3>
            <div class="a-center">                        
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability"><span class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <ul class="add-to-links">
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                    <li class="last"><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php $i++; endforeach; $kol = $_collectionSize; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and use this code in cms home page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_mostviewed" template="catalog/product/mostviewed.phtml"}}
```

i am getting products but without name, 0 price & place holder image
[image]

Comment: Your code looks perfectly alright. I added the above code on my test website and it is showing the products

Answer (score 2):

Has to do with flat catalog.

Fix in php-file is to include:

```
if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {
    $products->getSelect()->joinInner(array('e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_'.$storeId), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
}
```

Comment: Please Check this link.http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82604/product-list-page-sort-by-most-view-can-we-sort-this-by-page-views-hits

Answer (score -1):

Your code run very well with my modules. With your problem, I think you should check your database( I use magento-sample-data-1.9.1.0 db)